# Trying to use BeautifulSoup to find a specific table in an HTML doc

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The HTLM page I'm trying to read has 21 tables.  The specific table I'm trying to reference is unique in that is has a unique `<caption>` and not all tables even have a caption.

Here is a snippet of the structure:

```
<table class="wikitable">
    <caption>Very long caption</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr align="center" bgcolor="#efefef">
```

I've tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
table1 = soup.find('table', caption="Very long caption")
```

But returns a `None` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `soup.find('table', caption="Very long caption")`

This basically means - locate a `table` element that has a `caption` attribute having `Very long caption` value. This obviously returns nothing.

What I would do is to locate the `caption` element by text and get the [parent `table` element](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
soup.find("caption", text="Very long caption").find_parent("table")
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.